# Get Token JSON with Python (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 )

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to make a webscrape in a website but I cannot obtain the **Bearer** or **Token** with my user and password (please tell me if there is any way I can share these with you in a private manner).

Here is my code...

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://200.75.4.210:8080/'}
login = {
    'Password': "CXXXXXX",
    'Usuario': "eXXXXXX"}
response = requests.post('http://200.75.4.210:8080/CIODCH/login.aspx', headers=headers, data=login).json()
```

Can anybody help me finding the cause of the error ?

Comment: Premature assumption that response is json can be very disappointing as you are finding; perhaps add code to check the response is JSON, perhaps check the first character is [ or {, and if it isn’t log or print what you’ve received?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody help me finding the cause of the error ?

You can get the pre-json result with

```
response = requests.post('http://200.75.4.210:8080/CIODCH/login.aspx', headers=headers, data=login)
```

This can be analysed further in the REPL:

```
response.status_code  # 200
response.content  # b'\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\r\n    <meta conte...
```

This looks like HTML, not JSON. How about sending the application/json accept header ?